# Update links in Laravel for server from local

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, storage, symlink

I statred creating project in Laravel. One of his method adds images to storage/app/public. To make this operation I had to call method:

`php artisan storage:link`

On my local server (I use to Xamp) it works perfectly. I have a problem after updating files on the external server. When I try open link to files in storage/app/public browser returns "error 404".

I wanted to call storage::link method on external server, but it didn't work (server blocks symlink() method).

I want to ask you do you know how resolve this problem? I have idea calling this method on local server, but with server url in parameters, but I don't know how do it.

Comment: Can you please check if the storage folder has enough permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/storage-link', function (){
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Add this in web.php and hit the URL once and then remove it

Comment: I tried this method, but server blocked it too.

Comment: Only solution i see here is to manually transfer all files from storage/app/public/ into public/storage/. If server blocks symlinks there's not much you can do about it.